# prove $(\frac{n+1}{n})^n < (\frac{n}{n-1})^n$ if $n\geq2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

$$(\frac{n+1}{n})^n < (\frac{n}{n-1})^n$$

To prove the first case we'll replace n=2

LHS$\Rightarrow \frac{9}{4}$

RHS$\Rightarrow 4$

We can clearly see that LHS is  less than RHS therefore first case is proven

Now we must assume that $n=k$ and $k\geq2$

$$(\frac{k+1}{k})^k < (\frac{k}{k-1})^k$$

Now we will have to prove for $n=k+1$

$$(\frac{k+2}{k+1})^{k+1} < (\frac{k+1}{k})^{k+1}$$

What i've tried to do from this point is working from the induction hypothesis

$(\frac{k+1}{k})^k < (\frac{k}{k-1})^k $ multiplying both sides by $(\frac{k+1}{k})$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{k+1}{k})^{k+1} < (\frac{k}{k-1})^k(\frac{k+1}{k})$

But that doesn't get me any closer. If anyone can help it'll be cool

Comment: I suggest rewriting it as $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)^n$$ and comparing $1+\frac1n$ with $1+\frac1{n-1}$.

Comment: Along similar lines, you could also cross multiply to get the equivalent inequality $(n^2 - 1)^n < (n^2)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested:

$$ ((n+2)n)^{n+1}=(n^2+2n)^{n+1}<(n^2+2n+1)^{n+1}=((n+1)^2)^{n+1} $$

which straightforwardly proves the inductive (and actually all) steps.

Answer (score 0):

well we can first observe that the power on both sides are equal and is a positive number greater than or equal to 2.

now clearly (n+1)/n≤ 1≤ (n-1)/n
now raising a power n≥2 the inequality sign remains unchanged,

hence {(n+1)/n}^n < {(n-1)/n}^n.

Answer (score 0):

$(n^2-1)^{n}<(n^2)^n$
$\Rightarrow ((n-1)(n+1))^n<n^n
 \Rightarrow (\frac{n+1}{n})^n<(\frac{n}{n-1})^n$

We also get $(\frac{n-1}{n})^n<(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that 
$n^2-1\leq n^2$ which implies $(n+1)(n-1)\leq n^2$ which further gives $\frac{n+1}{n}\leq \frac{n}{n-1}.$ Raising to the power $n$ on both the sides you get the result.